# QGraphicsPathItem different colors

Tags: python, pyside, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

Is there a way to get 2 different fill colors for a single `QGraphicsPathItem` object?

For example:

```
    # Try to get a white text onto a grey rectangle
    itemPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    itemPath.setFillRule(QtCore.Qt.WindingFill)

    self.setBrush( QtGui.QColor(100, 100, 100) )
    itemPath.addRect(-10, -60, 150, 70)
    itemFont = QtGui.QFont()
    itemFont.setPointSize(50)
    self.setBrush( QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255) )
    itemPath.addText(0, 0, itemFont, txt)
```

Right now it's just using the last brush color for the rectangle and text. I'd like to color them differently though, but still as the same `QGraphicsPathItem`. Or better yet, a way to give the text a background so it's easier to select.

**Update**

Here's an example. I want a white text with a red background, but I only get the last used brush color.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class TextItem(QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TextItem, self).__init__()

        itemPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        itemPath.setFillRule(QtCore.Qt.WindingFill)

        # Create rectangle with red color
        self.setBrush( QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0) )
        itemPath.addRect(-10, -50, 130, 60)
        self.setPath(itemPath)

        # Create text with white color
        itemFont = QtGui.QFont()
        itemFont.setPointSize(40)
        self.setBrush( QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255) )
        itemPath.addText(0, 0, itemFont, 'Test!')
        self.setPath(itemPath)

        self.moveBy(100, 100)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene( QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self) )
        self.view.setSceneRect( 0, 0, 500, 500 )
        self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)        

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        newItem = TextItem()
        self.view.scene().addItem( newItem )

    def run(self):
        self.show()

win = Window()
win.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a minimal running example: since it requires a QGraphicsView and so on and therefore is not trivial to set up.  But it is possible to make it small enough to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your first `self.setPath` and `self.setBrush` calls are just over-ridden by the second ones.  These properties of the `QGraphicsPathItem` are not used until you get to the paint event.  So the first settings do nothing and the values left in these properties after the initialisation are the ones used to paint the item.

It's not too difficult to do what you want but you have quite a lot of options, and you need to choose based on other aspects of your design.

The simplest option would be to just create a `QGraphicsRectItem` and then give it a `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` child.  This is particularly simple in that you wouldn't even need to create a subclass of your own: simply create the instances, set their Paths and Brushes and use them directly.  I strongly recommend this approach if it does what you neeed.

```
    rectItem = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 130, 60)
    rectItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))

    textItem = QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem("Test!",rectItem)

    itemFont = QtGui.QFont()
    itemFont.setPointSize(40)
    textItem.setBrush( QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200) )
    textItem.setFont(itemFont)
    textItem.setPos(10,0)

    self.view.scene().addItem( rectItem )

    rectItem.moveBy(100,100)
```

Another simple option would be just create the two items and then add them into a `QGraphicsItemGroup`.  This makes sense if you might want to separate the items or work with them separately.

```
    rectItem = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 130, 60)
    rectItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
    self.view.scene().addItem( rectItem )
    textItem = QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem("Test!")
    itemFont = QtGui.QFont()
    itemFont.setPointSize(40)
    textItem.setBrush( QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200) )
    textItem.setFont(itemFont)
    textItem.setPos(10,0)
    self.view.scene().addItem( textItem )
    group = QtGui.QGraphicsItemGroup()
    group.addToGroup(rectItem)
    group.addToGroup(textItem)
    group.moveBy(100,100)
    self.view.scene().addItem( group )
```

If you need to create a class of your own for other reasons then you have quite a few options.  The most general will be to subclass `QGraphicsItem`.  You can create a `MyTextItem` with, for example, two Paths and two Brushes, and use them both when you paint the Item.  You will have to implement `boundingRect` and `paint` but in this case both will be quite easy.  This is probably a good way to go if you foresee adding lots of additional functionality to the item.

Other options would be to subclass `QRectItem` and add a text path to it.  Again you will need to re-implement `paint`, but that might be all that was needed.  Or you could subclass `QSimpleTextItem` and add a rect to it.

Comment: I was hoping to stick with `QGraphicsPathItem` to keep everything in a single class, but this looks good to me. Thank you for the great explanation!

Comment: QGraphicsPathItem does its drawing on the basis of its own Path and Brush.  So the only way to do that would be to override paint and boundingRect.  But various other methods would also then be rather odd, eg setPath. contains, and so on.  It just doesn't really make sense.